# Bypass remote control and connect harbor breeze to wall switch with fan speed and light control

Tags: ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I had to replace my patio ceiling fan.  The replacement unit came with a remote control, which I did not notice until installation time.

I installed a wall switch for the previous fan which controlled:

1. Light on / off (toggle switch)
2. Light dimmer (slider on one side of the toddle switch)
3. 3-speed fan control (slider on the other side of the toggle switch)

I had to pull a separate single wire from the switch to the fan for this to work.  It worked fine.

How do I bypass / split the remote control function so I can use the wall switch / fader / fan control?

Comment: *pull a separate single wire* Do you have individual wires in conduit? Or do you have (except for this separate single wire) typical NM (a.k.a. Romex) cables?

Comment: I pulled a separate single wire so both the 3-wire romex and the single wire controlled all three functions of the wall switch - light on/off (toggle), dimmer (slider) and fan speed (slider).  That worked, how do I bypass the remote control module and splice the 'other' side to those wires so I can use the wall switch as I previously did.

Comment: What model is your new fan?

Comment: Harbor Breeze Summersville 52-in Textured Black LED Indoor/Outdoor Ceiling Fan with Light Remote (5-Blade) - Item #3856486 - Model #42192

Comment: "3-wire Romex" - is that black/white/red/bare? (4 wires, one of which is bare ground and not counted in the traditional /3 nomenclature) or is it black/white/bare? (3 physical wires)? Are there any other cables going into the switch box?

Comment: 3-wire romex, normal residential interior hot/neutral/ground - separate wire of same guage - wall switch controls light on/off, fader (when on), fan speed (independent of light) - romex can handle light on/off/fader -or- fan speed but not both, that's what the separate wire handles from the switch to the fan.  Simple h/n/g romex feeds the switch, extra wire from switch to fan.

Comment: That is actually referred to as "/2" - i.e., the 3rd wire is a bare ground and grounds all connect to each other and to metal boxes but aren't "counted".

Comment: Pulling one additional _wire_ and using it in a circuit in conjunction with NM-B "Romex" _cable_ is not code compliant! Do the fan instructions say you can bypass the remote? Has Harbor Breeze customer service given you any indication if and how you can do this? Have you considered returning the device that you've determined is not suitable for purpose to pick up one that _is_?

Comment: @FreeMan This fan/light, as with most that I have looked at in the past several years, has the remote receiver as a separate unit bundled with the fan/light. I suspect that is (a) because different regions may need different remotes due to frequency allocations and (b) so that people who are installing in new construction or who are able to retrofit a bigger cable can connect with wired dimmers and fan controls. The new construction people aren't going to read the manual :-) But I'm a little surprised they don't include wired directions for people who want to install wired switches themselves

Comment: which actually may not be that unusual, particularly if it is a "already two switches" replacement. There are other advantages - e.g., if someone wants the fan/light as part of a "smart ecosystem" then wired with smart switches works better than a cheapie wireless remote.

Answer (score 1):

##### Code violation!

Based on comments, the existing configuration uses a 3-wire cable + 1 single wire. But this 3-wire cable really only has two functional wires (black switched hot and white neutral) plus a bare ground wire.

You (a) can't have single wires without them being protected by conduit and (b) can't combine single wires with cables because currents must be balanced within each cable or conduit.

So there are really two separate issues here:

- How do you properly wire two switched hot wires + neutral?
- How do you wire a fan for switch control instead of wireless remote control?

The first part can be properly done one of two ways:

- A /3 cable - black switched hot, red switched hot, white neutral, bare ground.
- Conduit with individual wires for two switched hots and neutral.

Generally speaking fishing a new cable through will be easier than running conduit. In this particular case, you can probably use the existing single wire as a pull string to pull through a new cable and then abandon the old /2 cable. Note that if this is a 20A circuit then you must use 12 AWG cable. If it is a 15A circuit then you can use 14 AWG cable or 20 AWG cable.

According to [the manual on Lowes web site](https://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/cb6cd939-49d1-46b9-b5a4-70d917d46cb5/48509052.pdf?_gl=1*fraax3*_gcl_au*MTEzMTY0MjczMi4xNjkxMDA1MjMy), the remote is a separate receiver box, and the *real* wiring is:

- blue = light switched hot
- black = fan switched hot
- white = neutral (standard)
- green = ground (standard)

So wire things up as follows:

In the switch box:

- black hot to two pigtails to the dimmer and fan controls.
- white neutral to white wire in new cable. If the switches need neutral then connect pigtails to the switches as well.
- dimmer switched hot to /3 red wire
- fan control switched hot to /3 black wire

In the ceiling:

- Don't connect the remote receiver.
- Connect cable white to fan white.
- Connect cable bare ground to fan green.
- Connect cable black to fan black.
- Connect cable red to fan blue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and it was somebody at the store who told me to simply connect a single cable of same gauge (red sheathing in this case) to either of the slider connections to power either the dimmer or speed control.  That solution has been in place for 15 years.  But to your point, clipping the 4x wires at the point of connection on the remote control receiver results in 'normal' connections for separate controls of light and fan via wall switch - got it, that's the part I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: @dshorrosh please be careful getting advice from the _sales associates_ at big box stores. Usually, they're well meaning, but are often clueless about how to actually do things with the products they sell. _Sometimes_ you'll find someone who has worked in the trade of the line of products (s)he is selling, but that's rare. If you go to an electrical or plumbing supply house, you'll _most likely_ get good advice from the person at the counter.